# How to get the each album songs and album artwork,songs list and play count in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I need to implement this functionality please help me.

1st viewcontroller

I'm using this code for getting the albums artwork.This is working fine but,i want show the songs list  and play count.When i select album here means [1st viewcontroller],we go the 2nd viewcontroller and show the list of songs and if we select the song that will play.
Thanks.

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[query setGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingAlbum];

NSArray *albums = [query collections];
NSMutableArray *albumsWithArt = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[albums count]];
for (id album in albums) {
    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [[album representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    if (artwork) {
        [albumsWithArt addObject:album];
    }
}
self.albums = [NSArray arrayWithArray:albumsWithArt];
```

Comment: Can you give the sample code for this.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.Now I am  getting each album song,Which I selected the album.
May be this solution useful,Who has same functionality.

```
MPMediaQuery *albumsQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
        NSArray *albums = [albumsQuery collections];
        NSArray * al = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], nil];
        MPMediaItemCollection *albumCollection;
        for (albumCollection in al) {
            NSString *selectedAlbumTitle = [[albumCollection representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
            NSMutableDictionary * dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dic setObject:selectedAlbumTitle forKey:@"AlbumName"];
            NSArray *songs = albumCollection.items;
            NSLog(@"album title is %@",selectedAlbumTitle);
            NSMutableArray * songsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
                NSLog(@"the album songs title is--->%@",[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
                [songsArray addObject:[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]];
            }
            [dic setObject:songsArray forKey:@"Song"];
            [localSongsList addObject:dic];
            NSLog(@"alub song list %@",localSongsList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take seperate array for each Album and allocate memory, so that array will refresh for every new album .

```
NSArray * albumsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[albums
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], nil];
                MPMediaItemCollection *albumCollection;
                for (albumCollection in albumsArray) {
                    NSString *selectedAlbumTitle = [[albumCollection representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
                    NSMutableDictionary * dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                    [dic setObject:selectedAlbumTitle forKey:@"AlbumName"];
                    NSArray *songs = albumCollection.items;
                    NSLog(@"album title is %@",selectedAlbumTitle);
                    NSMutableArray * songsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
                        NSLog(@"the album songs title is--->%@",[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
                        [songsArray addObject:[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]];
                    }
                    [dic setObject:songsArray forKey:@"Song"];
                    [localSongsList addObject:dic];
                    NSLog(@"alub song list %@",localSongsList);
                }
```